# What is the symbol before the $\pmod M$?

Tags: notation, equivalence-relations

What is this?

$$\LARGE q \not\equiv 0 \pmod M$$

It looks like it would be the opposite of equivalence but then if that’s the case, I don’t know how to read the expression…

Comment: You could just read a few posts using this, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685285/prove-x-is-not-congruent). As the title there says, it means that $x$ is not congruent to $15$ modulo $17$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$q \not \equiv 0 \pmod{M}$ means $q$ is not congruent to $0$ modulo $M$.

Comment: A comment to this effect would have sufficed. If answered, I suggest community wiki.